# async.js return last value when use waterfall method

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

all. I'm using asyncjs's waterflow method to return res value at last.But following code is return undefined value.

```
var async = require("async");
User.findBy = function(name,password){
  async.waterfall([
      function fetch(callback){
        db.lrange("users",0,-1,function(err,users){
          users.forEach(function(item){
            var u = JSON.parse(item);
            if ((u.name == name) && (u.password == password)){
              console.log(u);
              callback(null,u);
              return;
            }
          });
        });
        callback(null);
      }
      ],function end(err,res){

        setTimeout(function(){
        // I want to return res value at last.
        return u;
        },0);
      });
};
```

#### app.js

```
 // but it returns undefined value.
 var user = User.findBy("nobinobiru",a");
```

Do you have any idea? Please any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know asyncjs, but it sounds like you're trying to get the result synchronously (that's what `var user =` and `return` imply). Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: The `User.findBy` doesn't have return statement so its return value is `undefined`. Make it take a callback and call that.

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do the way you're trying to do it. Also, using "waterfall" when you've just got one function to call seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fetch function you calling callback(null); immediately after the db.lrange call. This call unnecessary here, because you need to wait results from db.

This code should work fine:

```
var async = require("async");
User.findBy = function(name,password){
    async.waterfall([
        function fetch(callback){
            db.lrange("users",0,-1,function(err,users){
                var user;
                if (users && users.length) {
                    users.forEach(function(item){
                        var u = JSON.parse(item);
                        if ((u.name == name) && (u.password == password)){
                            console.log(u);
                            user = u;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    callback(null,user);
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
            });
        }
    ],function end(err,res){

        setTimeout(function(){
            // I want to return res value at last.
            return res;
        },0);
    });
};
```